# Find and update a hash by HashKey to add record for saving

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have an array of hashes:

```
hash = [{"one": 1}, {"two": 2}]
```

And I want to find a hash and add to it. For example find "one" and add:

```
hash =  [{"one": 1, "new": new}, {"two": 2}]
```

I could do this by hash key? If so how would I do it? Or is there a much better way to do this thing in Javascript? I dont want to copy the hash, make a new one and delete the old one. Just update what is already there.

Comment: would you be happy to use a library, like underscore.js?

Comment: yes of I am using it already for somethings

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is pretty dynamic so you should be able to do something like this:

```
var hash = [{"one": 1}, {"two": 2}];

var hLength = hash.length;
for(int i=0; i<hLength; i++){         // Loop to find the required object.
   var obj = hash[i];

   if(obj.hasOwnProperty('one')){     // Condition you're looking for
       obj["new"] = "new";            // Property you wish to add.
       break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function I just wrote to do this.

```
/*
 * hashes - (array) of hashes
 * needle - (string) key to search for / (int) index of object
 * key - (string) key of new object you wish to insert
 * value - (mixed) value of new object you wish to insert
 */

function addToHash(hashes, needle, key, value) {
  var count = hashes.length;
  // If needle is a number treat it as an array key
  if (typeof needle === 'number' && needle < count) {
    hashes[needle][key] = value;
    return true;
  } else {
    // Search hashes for needle
    for (var i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
      if (needle in hashes[i]) {
        hashes[i][key] = value;
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: could the needle be $$hashkey?

Comment: @CharlieDavies I'm not sure of the significance of the `$$` but if `$$hashkey` is a string and that is the name of a key in the hash then yes. Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to use underscore you could get it done by starting with:

```
var hashes = [{"one": 1}, {"two": 2}];

var changed = _.map(hashes, function(hash){
    if(hash.one) {
        hash["new"] = "new";
        return hash
    }
    return hash;
});
```

You could generalise it a bit by passing a filter function to encapsulate the if statement, and another function to encapsulate the modification to the hash.

**EDIT** If you want to generalise what to look for in the hash, this could work:

```
var hashes = [{"one": 1}, {"two": 2}];

var isOne = function(hash) {
    return hash.one;
}

var addNew = function(hash) {
    hash["new"] = "new";
    return hash;
}

var hashChanger = function(filter, editor) {
    return function(hash) {
        if(filter(hash)) {
            return editor(hash);
        }
        return hash;
    }
}

var changed = _.map(hashes, hashChanger(isOne, addNew));
```

Comment: how could i do this though without needing to know the hash? in the example it is one. However they will be dynamic. Hashkey?